# Is it possible to use methods in java library or a java project snapshot in a protractor project?

Tags: automated-testing, java, protractor, quality-assurance, jasmine

If I create database testing project using java and export to a snapshot(as a jar), can I use it in a protractor project?

Hoping to use in protractor project,
protractor,jasmine framework along with visual studio code

Hoping to use in database project,
java,testNG,JDBC,intellij Idea

I can't use same technology for both API and E2E testing. Therefore I want to use database testing project in both API and E2E testing.

I know how to do in API project.What I don't know is whether I can use snapshot in protractor project.

If I can do it, should I expose database related methods as just a public method or as an API?

Comment: Voting to close, because it is a software development question. Although you are talking about Protractor, in the end, the question talks about calling Java from Node/Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way we can call Java methods/classes in Protractor, here is the reference link of discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29985297/1976848.

But as in you Ques of using DB in protractor project, so you can use the same DB created for database testing project, checkout this reference [Database connection with Protractor](https://chercher.tech/protractor/database-connection)
 with this you can use snapshots in Protractor Project.

I hope this might help you!! let me know if it works.